# two table Users Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC-4 Project in which i have to Authenticate if the User is Signed in from Users in Customers Table or Merchants Table.

I can do that like code bellow that if user exist in that Table or Not.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && BlCustomer.Where(x => x.Email == User.Identity.Name).Any())
```

My Problem is when i have the same User on Both Tables.how could i know that which User is Signed in? he is from Customers Table or Merchants Table?
Cause tables has different designs and i cant get them in one table.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare by signed in user primary key and name in database to identity user belong to which table.

You can get user id by this.

```
User.Identity.GetUserId<int>().
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Hello Friend thanks . but there is no GetUserId for me.

Comment: There should be namespace for that.

Comment: i couldn't find any namespace for that,i think its for MVC5. my Project is MVC4.

Comment: i added using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity and got GetUserId. but it returns Zero everytime.